# Is there a way to create relative links to an InDesign template file?

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

Just like the title says, I'm trying to create relative paths to an Illustrator file and Excel file in my template file. I'm using data merge to create a bunch of files from the template and when I the individual InDesign files, I run a script that places each of the new documents into a folder with the same name. I am then dropping the linked files into the new folders and kept the files the same name and kept the same file structure. So, if it were a relative path, it would update. But, it shows up as a missing link. After I make the files, I am running a script to open the files, update links, and export a PDF; so, manually updating the links kinda defeats the purpose.

If there's not a way to create a relative path, is there a script out there that will look for a file of the same file type and/or filename in the same folder as the document?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I’ve tried reading your description four times now, and I simply cannot understand it. Can you please try to describe your workflow more accurately?

Comment: Don't know about a script.. but from the Link Panel, choose 1 missing link... and then use the Panel menu to chose `Relink to Folder`. Choose the new folder. ID asks if you want to update other links found there as well. That *should* be scriptable, but I'm not the one to ask that `:)`

Comment: Sorry @JanusBahsJacquet, I know it's complex, but I'm not sure I can describe it differently.

Comment: @Scott Ya, that's what I'm thinking. There's gotta be a way to do it. I have a script that updates the links, but doesn't work with missing links. I'm trying to go through all of the forums to see if somebody knows a way to make it scriptable. So far, unsuccessful. Thank you, though!

Comment: ermm.. https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/relink-missing-links-with-script/m-p/9375885 (no endorsement though. I haven't tried it.) There's also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFZIPDhEkqY -- but I assume you've found these already.